# Need advice for Motel rewire 58 room one story very messy and multiple rooms on one circuit

Tags: electrical

So I have a rewire and a panel upgrade for a motel that is absolutely a disaster multiple rooms on one circuit multiple circuits containing multiple different plugs and different rooms it's just a disaster and I'm trying to figure out how the best way to tackle this would be when they don't want to let me turn off any power but one room at a time basically and the owners don't want to lose a room so they're all occupied I'm just having a hard time getting the ball rolling I keep running into just weird every different type of anomaly you can imagine does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Unless you are a license electrician, then it is most likely illegal for you to touch anything to do with the panel or circuits.  Some places do allow the average home owner to work on their own home, but any rentals is a big no-no.  What the owners want does not matter if not safe.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a motel is clearly commercial and out of scope for DIY.

Comment: The owners probably do not get much of a say of how to do the job, besides planning the best time when some rooms/wings can be shut down.  Depending on the mess, they might not even get that, if an inspector says so.

Answer (score 7):

### This brought to you by the name "project planning"

A job like this is all about pre-planning every move.  Basically you are going to run all the new wire while the old wire is still in use.  Then cut it over when ready.

Further, you are most likely going to need (from code) or want (for practicality) to run this in conduit - though at a limit of 4 circuits per pipe.   The main reason is you can build empty conduit *through a room* when you have access to it, and then later, you can pull wire through that conduit without having to disturb the occupants of the room or making a mess.  This also saves you a bit on wire since metal conduit provides the ground path.

Also, it is easy to do conduit work *piecemeal* so you work on one little area at a time - there is no need to run the entire cable run in one go, like it is with cable.   Again all this is about project planning.

Also if you are not entirely quite a licensed electrician, running empty conduit is not entirely quite "electrical work" lol.  But once the conduit is in, it makes fast work of actually pulling the wires, so it won't take so much of the expensive guy's time.  Helps to have pulling ropes already in the conduit and all the lengths known/correct.

Answer (score 3):

1. Run. Away. Fast. :)
2. If #1 is undoable, show the owner the problem about multiple rooms being on one circuit. Explain that for a short time, each circuit must be turned off  while you isolate one room. Then disconnect that room's wires from the circuit, cap the wires with nuts etc, then make the rest of the circuit safe and restore power to the other rooms on the circuit. Rinse and repeat as necessary.